# STM8 Захват по входу

Tags: c, микроконтроллеры

Есть у меня МК stm8s103f3p6, использую для написания IAR workbench 3.11.1 и китайский свисток ST-Link V2.
Возникла следующая проблема: мне нужно осуществить захват сигнала по входу по спадающему фронту, то есть, когда на ноге C3 перирдически то появляется то пропадает сигнал с определённой частотой, то должно, по идее, вызываться прерывание захвата/сравнения, где я могу посмотреть, что там натикал таймер TIM1 и что-то с этим значением сделать. Собстенно этого то и не просходит, и программа не заходит в прерывание. Ногу МК вручную замыкаю на землю проводом.

```
#include <iostm8s103f3.h>
#include <stdint.h>

void CLK_HSI_16MHZ_init(){
  CLK_CKDIVR_bit.HSIDIV = ((uint8_t)0x00); / устанавливаем делитель частоты = 1
}

void INTERRUPT_ON(){
  asm("RIM");
}

#pragma vector = TIM1_CAPCOM_CC3IF_vector
__interrupt void TIM1_CAP_CH3(void){
  TIM1_SR1_bit.CC3IF = 0; // тут пока ничего не делаем и сбрасываем флаг прерывания (тут стоит брейкпоинт отладчика)
}

void TIM1_init(void){
  TIM1_CR1_bit.CEN = 0; // для перестраховки явным образом отключаем TIM1

  PC_DDR_bit.DDR3 = 0;
  PC_CR1_bit.C13 = 1;
  PC_CR2_bit.C23 = 0;   // настраиваем PC3 как вход с подтяжкой к питанию (как это рекомендуют в мануале)
  
  TIM1_CCER2_bit.CC3E = 0;   // для перестраховки явным образом отключаем 3-й канал захвата/сравнения
  TIM1_CCMR3_bit.CC3S = 1;   // настраиваем путь сигнала 3-го канала по пути TI3FP3
  TIM1_CCMR3_bit.OC3M = 0x0; // устанавливаем количество семплов равным нулю
  TIM1_CCER2_bit.CC3P = 1;   // сравнение по спадающему фронту
  TIM1_IER_bit.CC3IE = 1;    // включем прерывания на 3-ем канале
  
  TIM1_CCER2_bit.CC3E = 1;   // включаем 3-й канал
  TIM1_CR1_bit.CEN = 1;      // включаем TIM1
}

int main( void )
{
  CLK_HSI_16MHZ_init();
  INTERRUPT_ON();
  TIM1_init();  
  while(1){
  }
  return 0;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Вход третьего канала TIM1 помечен как альтернативная функция PC3 по умолчанию, так что необходимость ремапа option bits я сразу отмёл.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для включения альтернативной функции пина, как я понял, нужно просто включить сам 3-й канал TIM1, так как в мануале написано, что это включается соответствующим регистром переферии. Так что и тут всё верно.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Можно предположить, что надо сконфигурировать сам пин с подтяжкой и прерыванием, но, как видно из схемы выше, вход альтернативной функции канала подключён параллельно со входом прерывания самого пина, так что в этом нет необходимости.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил я свою проблему. Внимательность - наше всё. В ходе работы мне понадобилось использовать эмулятор МК, после чего я благополучно забыл переставить режим отладки с симулятора МК на стлинк, с чем и было связано отсутствие входа в прерывание ввиду того, что у симулированного МК на ногах не было сигнала.
Пусть это будет уроком для таких, как я.
Прошу прощения за потраченное время.